# Find the inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac{12(s-2)}{(s^2-4s+85)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I am just beginning my study on Laplace transform and I am stuck by a problem asking me to find the inverse Laplace transform of:

$$\dfrac{12(s-2)}{(s^2-4s+85)^2} \tag{$\ast$}$$

Here the definition of inverse Laplace transform is: If $L(f(t)) = F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t)$ defines a Laplace transform, then the inverse Laplace transform is $L^{-1}(F(s)) = f(t)$.

**My attempt:** I wrote $s^2-4s+85$ as $(s-2)^2+ 9^2$ and tried to write $(*)$ as a sum of something, but I failed.

Can somebody give me some hint for this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ \dfrac{12(s-2)}{(s^2-4s+85)^2} \right](t)
= 12 \cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{s-2}{(s-2)^2 + 9^2} \cdot \frac{1}{(s-2)^2 + 9^2}\right](t)
$$
by your algebraic manipulations and linearity.

Now you just need to know the following:

- The Laplace transforms of sine and cosine:
  $$
  \mathcal{L} \left[ \sin \alpha t \right](s) = \frac{\alpha}{s^2 + \alpha^2}
  \qquad
  \mathcal{L} \left[ \cos \alpha t \right](s) = \frac{s}{s^2 + \alpha^2}
  $$
- The shifting property:
  $$
  \mathcal{L}[e^{\alpha t} f(t)](s) = \mathcal{L}[f](s-\alpha)
  $$
- The convolution theorem: defining
  $$
  (f\ast g)(t) := \int_0^t f(t-\tau) g(\tau) \, \mathrm{d} \tau
  $$
  we have
  $$
  \mathcal{L}[f \ast g](s) = \mathcal{L}[f](s) \cdot \mathcal{L}[g](s)
  $$

These should be enough to conclude.

Comment: Thanks for your advice here! But I don't quite understand the Convolution Theorem here, and could you please explain more on how to apply it here?

Comment: The idea is that you have a product of two functions, $F(s) \cdot G(s)$. Then you know that the inverse transform of the product is the convolution of each function individually transformed, $f(s) \ast g(s)$. That is, the Laplace transform turns convolution into products.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I now understand it!